# jQuery plugin only working on last selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

In my quest for learning more Javascript I'm trying to create a jQuery plugin that creates my own custom scrollbars. It is working fine for one scrollbar at a time but if I try to do two of them only the last one works.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JoelCool/K4mW7/1/

I've noticed the variable "scrolling" is not true on the first scrollbar in the HandleMouseMove() function so it seems like it might be a scoping thing?

HTML
    
    
    Scrollbar Test
    
    
        .scroller-bar {
            background-color:#ccc;border:1px solid black;float:left;position:relative;cursor:pointer;
        }
        .noSelect
        {
            user-select:none;
            -o-user-select:none;
            -moz-user-select:none;
            -khtml-user-select:none;
            -webkit-user-select:none;
        }

```
<div id="container" style="width:600px;height:300px;background-color:#ccc;overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
    <div id="content" style="background-color:blue;width:800px;height:283px;position:relative;left:0;">
        12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
    </div>
    <div style="top:0;left:0;height:300px;width:100px;background-color:yellow;z-index:100;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div id="scroll-track-h" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;height:17px;width:500px;background-color:cyan;"></div>
    <div id="scroll-track-v" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;height:283px;width:17px;background-color:orange;"></div>
</div>
<br /><br />

<script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="scroller.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#scroll-track-v').scroller();
    $('#scroll-track-h').scroller();
    //$('#scroll-track-v, #scroll-track-h').scroller();
</script>
```

Javascript

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.scroller = function( options ) {

    options = $.extend( $.fn.scroller.defaults, options );

    // Plugin code
    return this.each(function () {
        var $elem = $(this),
            scrolling = false,
            mouseStartPos = 0,
            barPos = 0,
            xy = $elem.width() > $elem.height() ? 'x' : 'y',    // x = horizontal, y = vertical
            trackLength = xy == 'x' ? $elem.width() : $elem.height(),
            barLength = (trackLength * options.barPct / 100) - 2,   // should make it figure out the border width
            travelLength = trackLength - barLength - 2;
        console.log($elem);
        var $bar = $('<div class="scroller-bar"></div>')
                    .width( xy == 'x' ? barLength : $elem.innerWidth() - 2)
                    .height( xy == 'x' ? $elem.innerHeight() - 2 : barLength);
        $elem.append($bar);

        $elem.on('mousedown', function (evt) {
            scrolling = true;
            $("body").addClass("noSelect"); // turn off text selection while scrolling
            mouseStartPos = xy == 'x' ? evt.pageX : evt.pageY;
            barPos = xy == 'x' ? $bar.position().left : $bar.position().top;
            $(document).on('mousemove', function (evt) { HandleMouseMove(evt); });
        });

        $(document).on('mouseup', function (evt) {
            if (scrolling) {
                $("body").removeClass("noSelect");
                $(document).off('mousemove');
                mouseStartPos = 0;
                scrolling = false;
            }
        });

        HandleMouseMove = function (evt) {
            console.log(scrolling);
            if (scrolling) {
                var mouseMovedBy = xy == 'x' ? evt.pageX - mouseStartPos : evt.pageY - mouseStartPos,
                    newBarPos = barPos + mouseMovedBy;
                if (newBarPos < 0) { newBarPos = 0; }
                if (newBarPos > travelLength) { newBarPos = travelLength; }
                $bar.css(xy == 'x' ? 'left' : 'top', newBarPos);
                var pct = newBarPos / travelLength;
            }
        }
    });
}

// Set up the default options.
$.fn.scroller.defaults = {
    barPct : 25,
    onScroll : null
};
})( jQuery );

$('#scroll-track-v').scroller();
$('#scroll-track-h').scroller();
```

I'm calling it on the vertical bar first and then the horizontal and only the horizontal works. If I switch them then only the vertical works.

Can anyone give me a clue?  Am I doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function HandleMouseMove() was not binded to the Element. It was getting mixed values for the 'scrolling' Boolean value.

I just added $elem. before the function name. and made it as $elem.HandleMouseMove(event);

Check the code

```
(function( $ ) {
$.fn.scroller = function( options ) {

    options = $.extend( $.fn.scroller.defaults, options );

    // Plugin code
    return this.each(function () {
        var $elem = $(this),
            scrolling = false,
            mouseStartPos = 0,
            barPos = 0,
            xy = $elem.width() > $elem.height() ? 'x' : 'y',    // x = horizontal, y = vertical
            trackLength = xy == 'x' ? $elem.width() : $elem.height(),
            barLength = (trackLength * options.barPct / 100) - 2,   // should make it figure out the border width
            travelLength = trackLength - barLength - 2;
        console.log($elem);
        var $bar = $('<div class="scroller-bar"></div>')
                    .width( xy == 'x' ? barLength : $elem.innerWidth() - 2)
                    .height( xy == 'x' ? $elem.innerHeight() - 2 : barLength);
        $elem.append($bar);

        $elem.on('mousedown', function (evt) {
            scrolling = true;
            $("body").addClass("noSelect"); // turn off text selection while scrolling
            mouseStartPos = xy == 'x' ? evt.pageX : evt.pageY;
            barPos = xy == 'x' ? $bar.position().left : $bar.position().top;
            $(document).on('mousemove', function (evt) { $elem.HandleMouseMove(evt); });
        });

        $(document).on('mouseup', function (evt) {
            if (scrolling) {
                $("body").removeClass("noSelect");
                $(document).off('mousemove');
                mouseStartPos = 0;
                scrolling = false;
            }
        });

        $elem.HandleMouseMove = function (evt) {
            console.log(scrolling);
            if (scrolling) {
                var mouseMovedBy = xy == 'x' ? evt.pageX - mouseStartPos : evt.pageY - mouseStartPos,
                    newBarPos = barPos + mouseMovedBy;
                if (newBarPos < 0) { newBarPos = 0; }
                if (newBarPos > travelLength) { newBarPos = travelLength; }
                $bar.css(xy == 'x' ? 'left' : 'top', newBarPos);
                var pct = newBarPos / travelLength;
            }
        }
    });
}

// Set up the default options.
$.fn.scroller.defaults = {
    barPct : 25,
    onScroll : null
};

 })( jQuery );

    $('#scroll-track-v').scroller();
    $('#scroll-track-h').scroller();
```

Check the Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shinde87sagar/K4mW7/3/

Comment: Nice! So was the issue with my HandleMouseMove function was that it was global? And so therefore getting the latest value for scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your code to work using data objects. When you have multiple DOM elements being worked on in a plugin, you should explicitly state which objects you're referring to. Keeping them global as you did makes it impossible for the `mousemove` and `mouseup` events to know which element to refer to. This way is cleaner and you only have to worry about the scope inside each event handler.

edit: this doesn't move the content pane yet, but this should give you an idea how to proceed correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy_og_kush/K4mW7/2/

```
$.fn.scroller = function( options ) {

    options = $.extend( $.fn.scroller.defaults, options );

    // Plugin code
    return this.each(function () {
        var $elem = $(this);            
        var xy = ($elem.width() > $elem.height() ? 'x' : 'y');
        var trackLength = (xy == 'x' ? $elem.width() : $elem.height());
        var barLength = (trackLength * options.barPct / 100) - 2;
        $elem.data({ 
            'scrolling' : false,
            'xy' : xy,
            'barPos' : 0,
            'mouseStartPos' : 0,
            'trackLength' : trackLength,
            'barLength' : barLength,
            'travelLength' : trackLength - barLength - 2
        });
        console.log($elem);
        var $bar = $('<div class="scroller-bar"></div>')
            .width($elem.data('xy') == 'x' ?
                       $elem.data('barLength') : 
                       $elem.innerWidth() - 2
            )
            .height($elem.data('xy') == 'x' ? 
                        $elem.innerHeight() - 2 : 
                        $elem.data('barLength')
            );
        $elem.append($bar).data('bar', $bar);

        $elem.on('mousedown', { elem : $elem }, function(evt) {
            evt.data.elem.data('scrolling', true);
            $thisBar = evt.data.elem.data('bar');
            $("body").addClass("noSelect"); 
            evt.data.elem.data('mouseStartPos', (
                evt.data.elem.data('xy') == 'x' ?
                    evt.pageX : 
                    evt.pageY
            ));
            evt.data.elem.data('barPos', (
                evt.data.elem.data('xy') == 'x' ?
                    $thisBar.position().left :
                    $thisBar.position().top
            ));
            $(document).on(
                'mousemove',
                { elem : evt.data.elem }, 
                HandleMouseMove
            );
        });

        $(document).on('mouseup', { elem : $elem }, function(evt) {
            if (evt.data.elem.data('scrolling') === true) {
                $("body").removeClass("noSelect");
                $(document).off('mousemove');
                mouseStartPos = 0;
                evt.data.elem.data('scrolling', false);
            }
        });

        HandleMouseMove = function(evt) {
            console.log(evt.data.elem.data('scrolling'));
            if (evt.data.elem.data('scrolling') === true) {
                var mouseMovedBy = (
                    evt.data.elem.data('xy') == 'x' ?
                        evt.pageX - evt.data.elem.data('mouseStartPos') :
                        evt.pageY - evt.data.elem.data('mouseStartPos')
                ),
                    newBarPos = evt.data.elem.data('barPos') + mouseMovedBy;
                if (newBarPos < 0) { newBarPos = 0; }
                if (newBarPos > evt.data.elem.data('travelLength')) {
                    newBarPos = evt.data.elem.data('travelLength'); 
                }
                evt.data.elem.data('bar').css(
                    (
                        evt.data.elem.data('xy') == 'x' ?
                            'left' : 
                            'top'
                    ),
                    newBarPos + "px"
                );
                //var pct = newBarPos / evt.data.elem.data('travelLength');
            }
        }
    });
}

// Set up the default options.
$.fn.scroller.defaults = {
    barPct : 25,
    onScroll : null
};

$('#scroll-track-v').scroller();
$('#scroll-track-h').scroller();
```

Comment: ++ That is excellent information that I did not know yet and makes a lot of sense for tracking the variable information.  I wasn't trying to move the content pane yet but intend to emit events since the case I'm working on the pane and scrollbars may not even be near each other. Many thanks!